# How to install Broadcom BCM4360 on debian on Macbook pro

Tags: debian, osx, broadcom

I'm trying to install the wireless drivers because my macbook pro does not have a ethernet port, then I mount the [3 debian isos](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/jessie_di_beta_2/amd64/iso-dvd/) like local repositories to install the almost all of dependeces.

So, what I tryed to do to install the broadcam 4360

https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx

https://wiki.debian.org/wl

When I try to install this:

http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

I get the following problems:

```
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-amd64'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-amd64'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  CC [M]  /home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_cfg80211_get_key’:
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:1390:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  memcpy(params.key, key.data, params.key_len);
  ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/bitmap.h:8,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:23,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/include/linuxver.h:40,
                 from /home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:26:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:32:14: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const u8 *’
 extern void *memcpy(void *to, const void *from, size_t len);
              ^
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: At top level:
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:1778:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .get_station = wl_cfg80211_get_station,
  ^
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:1778:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wl_cfg80211_ops.get_station’) [enabled by default]
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_notify_connect_status’:
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:2074:4: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘cfg80211_ibss_joined’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    cfg80211_ibss_joined(ndev, (u8 *)&wl->bssid, GFP_KERNEL);
    ^
In file included from /home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:33:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/net/cfg80211.h:4002:6: note: expected ‘struct ieee80211_channel *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned int’
 void cfg80211_ibss_joined(struct net_device *dev, const u8 *bssid,
      ^
/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:2074:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘cfg80211_ibss_joined’
    cfg80211_ibss_joined(ndev, (u8 *)&wl->bssid, GFP_KERNEL);
    ^
In file included from /home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:33:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/include/net/cfg80211.h:4002:6: note: declared here
 void cfg80211_ibss_joined(struct net_device *dev, const u8 *bssid,
      ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/scripts/Makefile.build:262: recipe for target '/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-common/Makefile:1350: recipe for target '_module_/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/cristian/Downloads/broadcom] Error 2
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-2-amd64'                                                                                                                                      
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed                                                                                                                                                          
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So if someone have installed the drivers to **Broadcom 4360** on mac with debian ,please tell me how, and what others  suggestions recommend me

Comment: I believe that device uses the "wl" driver http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205494

Answer (score 18):

**EDIT**

Broadcom 4360 actually comes with either of two distinct chips, 14E4:4360 and 14E4:43A0. There is no driver in Linux for the first one, while **wl** is an appropriate driver for the second one. You can determine which one you have by means of the following command:

```
 lspci -vnn | grep -i net
```

If instead you wish to do this from within Mac OS, hit the Apple -> About this Mac -> More Info-> System Info,  and then click on Wi-fi. You will find a line like

```
 Card Type: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x117)
```

which displays Vendor (14E4) and Product (117, in my case) code of the Wi-fi card.

---

There is no support for Broadcom 4360 14E4:4360 on Linux. The definitive guide in these matters is [Linux Wireless](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/), which gives [in this table](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43?highlight=%28b43%29#Supported_devices) the list of all Broadcomm wireless chips, and the available Linux drivers. As you can see, no driver is listed under BCM4360 14E4:4360.

Two lines below in the same table, it is shown that the other chip with which 4360 is produced, 14E4:43A0, is instead supported by the proprietary driver *wl*. The correct procedure to install this driver is described here, [in the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Debian_7_.22Wheezy.22). For Wheezy,
you should add this line

```
   deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

to the file /etc/apt/sources.list, then run

```
  apt-get update
  apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

and lastly you will need to remove some conflicting drivers which come pre-installed in Debian:

```
 modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
```

Now you are good to go:

```
 modprobe wl
```

You should also keep the following in mind: about the *wl* driver, this is what the ever informative [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl) has to say:

> **Warning**: Even though this driver has matured a lot throughout the years and works quite well now, its usage is recommended only when neither of the two open-source drivers support your device. Please refer to project b43's page for list of supported devices.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. NOTE to anyone who, like me, was having trouble with a reliable LAN connection on which to use apt-get: I needed a full downloadable package including dependencies for setting up wifi in debian on my late 2014 macbook pro 13 inch (with the BCM4360 14E4:43A0 chip), and I couldn't find such a package. So, by compiling .deb files manually downloaded for debian jessie, I made my own little wifi setup script. If anyone would like it, here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/00doasn3b3zh7eh/MacbookDebianWifi.zip?dl=0 Extract and run WifiSetup.sh

Comment: @MikeTurley the link is no longer valid.  I'm trying to install Qubes OS on my macbook pro mid 2014 and that link sounds like exactly what I need!  I've already switched out my sys-net VM for debian9.  So all i need is to copy the drivers over.

Comment: The only way  worked for me installing BCM4360 on kali linux single boot on a 2017 macbook air... Obviously adding the non-free deps from kali official documentation and not the deb deps!!!
Upvote for you :)

Comment: This answer works for Ubuntu 20.04 on MacBook Air A1466 (14e4:43a0 rev 3), while all the other answers mentioning bcmwl-kernel-source or firmware-b43-installer failed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Don't ever listen to anyone who tells you that you can't do something in linux, that's exactly why I no longer use windows.  :P

First, enable the nonfree repos. By adding "`non-free`" to your "`/etc/apt/sources.list`" file.

Then, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-*
sudo modprobe wl
echo "wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

**Do not forget the -a in the tee command or you will overwrite the whole file!!**

If it doesn't work right away, reboot and it should be fine.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205494

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/broadcom-sta-common/download

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=194&t=175030

Comment: You are partially right, not totally: BROADCOM 4360 comes with two chips (my bad, I had not noticed!), one is 14E4:4360 to which what I said applies, and one 14E4:43A0 for which *wl* is indeed the appropriate driver. I just hope for the OP that he has the latter one.

Comment: he was totally right. lol 2014 answer, that's OG

Comment: Recently I picked up an Apple Broadcom BCM94360CD for dual booting linux/hackintosh.  Running Zoron OS (Ubuntu variant) did not have to add non-free repo to the list, everything worked fine.

Comment: More quirks of BCM5360: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/broadcom_wireless#No_5GHz_for_BCM4360_(14e4:43a0)_/_BCM43602_(14e4:43ba)_devices