# How to Get BCM4360 Working On Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, macintosh

i'm trying to dual boot Kali Linux and OSX on a 2015 Macbook Air.
My macbook doesn't have any ethernet ports, so i can't do `sudo apt-get update`. I don't have any problems with rEFInd or the kali installation.

BTW:

I did some research and i think it can be installed via USB but i'm not sure .

How to Get BCM4360 Working On Kali Linux ?

Comment: Did you have an internet connection on kali linux ,e,g: mobile broadband , usb wifi ...?

Comment: +GAD3R no i don't

Comment: Related - [How to install Broadcom BCM4360 on debian on Macbook pro](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/how-to-install-broadcom-bcm4360-on-debian-on-macbook-pro)

Comment: +roaima thx but i don't have any type of connection to the internet so i can't do sudo apt-get update

Comment: So the question isn't really just about installing the Broadcom driver, it's about doing so without being able to download packages automatically? There are a number of questions with answers explaining how to handle the latter issue.

Comment: +roaima exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, it's possible to get a network connection so that you can get the BCM4360 drivers installed. But it won't be easy. And you have to be very careful or you'll cause bigger problems. Here's an overview of the process:

1. Basically, you can install Kali Linux in Virtual Box. Make sure networking is working from within Kali.
2. Then add the hard disk partition that Kali is installed on (in the Mac) to the Kali Virtual Box configuration, as a *second* disk. **WARNING: DON'T boot from the second disk in Virtual Box. And of course, make sure you select the correct partition.** You can read more about this process [here](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html).
3. Boot Kali within Virtual Box, and `mount` the second disk. That will provide filesystem access to the Kali installed in your Mac. To clarify, you're running Kali within Virtual Box, while also having access to the entire root filesystem of Kali installed natively on the Mac.
4. Setup a `chroot` environment on the mounted filesystem. You can reference the [Gentoo Linux](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base#Chrooting) install documentation to get an idea of how to set up a chroot.
5. Within the `chroot`, you're environment would be as if you're logged in to Kali natively; except you'll have a network connection because you're actually running Kali on Virtual Box with an emulated network card. Now, you can do your `apt-get` to install whatever you need. Any changes you make within `chroot` will occur on the native install of Kali.
6. Exit the `chroot`, `umount` the filesystem, and shutdown the Kali virtual machine. You can then boot your native Kali and take it from there.